# how to save canvas data to file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i am using node.js to save canvas to image 
img in writeFile is extractedby using toDataURL on my canvas element.
it doenot save file
here is my code

```
var fs = IMPORTS.require('fs');
var path = IMPORTS.require('path');
path.exists('images/', function(exists){
    if (exists) {

        fs.writeFile('images/icon.png', img, function(err){
            if (err) 
                callback({
                    error: false,
                    reply: err
                });
            console.log('Resized and saved in');
            callback({
                error: false,
                reply: 'success.'
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        callback({
            error: true,
            reply: 'File did not exist.'
        });
    }
 });
```

Comment: Can you include your canvas code or the url you are testing so that we can run your code without having to write any boilerplate? (see http://sscce.org/) You may also want to elaborate on your description a bit if you want people to help.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here is a literal example of how to save canvas data to a file in Nodejs. The variable `img` is a string generated by `canvas.toDataURL()`. I've assumed you already know how to POST that string from the browser to your Nodejs server.

HTML snippet that generates the sample image I used:

```
<canvas id="foo" width="20px" height="20px"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = $('#foo')[0].getContext('2d');
for (var x = 0; x < 20; x += 10) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 20; y += 10) {
        if (x == y) { ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'; }
        else { ctx.fillStyle = '#8888aa'; }
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}
console.log($('#foo')[0].toDataURL());
</script>
```

Nodejs snippet to decode the base64 data and save the image:

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;

(async () => {
  
  // string generated by canvas.toDataURL()
  const img = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0"
      + "NAAAAKElEQVQ4jWNgYGD4Twzu6FhFFGYYNXDUwGFpIAk2E4dHDRw1cDgaCAASFOffhEIO"
      + "3gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
  
  // strip off the data: url prefix to get just the base64-encoded bytes
  const data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
  
  const buf = Buffer.from(data, "base64");
  await fs.writeFile("image.png", buf);
})();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know i needed a `Buffer`, i was just trying to use `base64.decode()` with the base64 data, but generated a corrupt file.

Comment: The server code example works for me. Can someone explain me why it doesn't work with this data: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3yhGiQWR

Comment: I got buffer undefined

Comment: for me, the `toDataUrl()` string included plus signs which `body-parser` turned into whitespaces in `request.body`, so I had to replace them with plus signs again so that my png wasn't corrupt: `var data=img.slice(img.indexOf(',')+1).replace(/\s/g,'+');`

Comment: `new Buffer` has been deprecated [per nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/buffer-constructor-deprecation/). In this case you should use `Buffer.from(data, 'base64');` now.

Answer (score 22):

I believe that `Canvas` does not store it's data in Base64 internally. It should store data in some much more efficient binary format. So, obviously, transferring to base64 and back to binary PNG is terribly slow and memory consuming.

Quick googling to [node canvas documentation](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas) gives:

To create a PNGStream simply call canvas.pngStream(), and the stream will start to emit data events, finally emitting end when finished. If an exception occurs the error event is emitted.

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/text.png')
  , stream = canvas.pngStream();

stream.on('data', function(chunk){
  out.write(chunk);
});

stream.on('end', function(){
  console.log('saved png');
});
```

Currently only sync streaming is supported. If you want to do it async, you can try to use a worker or cluster (I personally never tried this).

Comment: The console.log('saved png') happens before the file is saved. Is this because only sync is supported? How could I get an event to fire _after_ the file has been saved?