# Uploading base64 encoded Image to Amazon S3 via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, coffeescript

Yesterday I did a deep night coding session and created a small node.js/JS (well actually CoffeeScript, but CoffeeScript is just JavaScript so lets say JS) app.

what's the goal:

1. client sends a canvas datauri (png) to server (via socket.io)
2. server uploads image to amazon s3

step 1 is done.

the server now has a string a la

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACt...
```

my question is: **what are my next steps to "stream"/upload this data to Amazon S3 and create an actual image there?**

knox https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox seems like an awesome lib to PUT something to S3, **but what I'm missing is the glue between the base64-encoded-image-string and actual upload action**?

Any ideas, pointers and feedback welcome.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867534/how-to-save-canvas-data-to-file/5971674#5971674

Answer (score 308, accepted):

For people who are still struggling with this issue. Here is the approach I used with native aws-sdk **:**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./s3_config.json');
var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'myBucket'} } );
```

Inside your router method (`ContentType` should be set to the content type of the image file):

```
  var buf = Buffer.from(req.body.imageBinary.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')
  var data = {
    Key: req.body.userId, 
    Body: buf,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
  };
  s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
      if (err) { 
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Error uploading data: ', data); 
      } else {
        console.log('successfully uploaded the image!');
      }
  });
```

s3_config.json file **:**

```
{
  "accessKeyId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "secretAccessKey":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "region":"us-east-1"
}
```

Comment: [MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Key' in params]

Comment: Key: req.body.userId
I used userId as key in post data... it was long back...


but you can declare any string as key. To make sure already present files are not overwritten keep the key unique.

Comment: @Divyanshu Thanks for such useful example. I got two doubt: `How to make S3 generates a unique KEY to prevent from overriding files?` and `If I don't set the ContentType, when I download the files I won't be able to get the correct file?` I mean, I will get such a corrupted file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Lexynux unique key is something you have to generate on your system. 
something like:-
aws_key : req.user.username + uuid(Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)) you can add more randomness to it to make sure that it does not clash. There is no specific rule here.

Comment: @Lexynux about content type, try to set content type beforehand, you can find code snippets in node to determine content-type of a file. not setting content-type might lead to corrupted files, I haven't verified this since I always set content-type before posting to s3

Comment: Alright @Divyanshu I will try to do so and if I need some more help I will write you back! Thanks a lot from México City!

Comment: @Divyanshu  
Buffer object will throw an error "Buffer not define" can you give me solution for that

Comment: @NaveenG You should not be getting that since Buffer class is part of javascript language. You might wanna check your javascript and node installation.

Comment: @NaveenG  Did you solve your error? I also face he same error

Comment: @Divyanshu Could you please help with the video upload as well?

Comment: @PushkarKathuria, The above approach should work for video as well. You just need to set the correct mime_type and base64 for video to read in buffer. For video base64 should take format like this - data:video/mp4;base64

Comment: From the docs it appears that the `upload` method returns the `location` in `data` but the `putObject` method does not. Do you know how to get the new S3 location path after a successful `putObject`?

Comment: @Marklar location path is basically key - e.g. if your bucket name is - bucketone and key name is xyz.png, then file path will be https://bucketone.s3.amazonaws.com/xyz.png

Comment: Thanks a lot ...I was confused with file name here the key is the filename and contain path as well. For example "/img/profile/userid.jpg" is work like a charm for me.

Comment: @Divyanshu Thanks for this great answer! It helped me a lot. However, I think `ContentEncoding: 'base64'` is not correct because `new Buffer(..., 'base64')` decodes base64-encoded string into its binary representation.

Comment: Hey @Divyanshu it's working, but I have a problem. Image is missing pixels in half of the portion. So image is not completely viewable. My decoded string is starting from  - /9j/4QO... after stripping those "data:image" and all.

Comment: @Divyanshu Also `replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "")` is not correctly finding data:image

Comment: @MeetZaveri, that's weird, this code still works for me. I used it in a new project recently. I am not sure how could I help more. Are you sure there is no issue with image or other settings ?

Comment: @Divyanshu it was done days before. No issues now. Your sol. provided an assist

Comment: Using the `Buffer` like that also works with the `upload()` function, too.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!!! I've been spending weeks on this and finally a straightforward solution.

Comment: Yes to what @ShuheiKagawa said; `ContentEncoding` is not necessary. Also, according to the latest Node.js docs, that form of the `Buffer` constructor is deprecated, replaced by `Buffer.from(..., 'base64')`.

Comment: Yes, @ShuheiKagawa is correct, ContentEncoding is unnecessary and actually caused my image urls served from S3 to be invalid for the Facebook API. You can test your urls here.. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

Comment: Just needed the ContentType, not sure why this too so long to find. AWS docs aren't the easiest to navigate.

Comment: @DivyanshuDas can i use .split(/base64,/)[1] insted of .replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "") ? because i want to upload any file. i am using AWS lambda and can't find any other method to upload file via lambda function.

Comment: Yes! `Body` should be a `Buffer` object.  not base64 string!

Comment: Working !! ........ this fixed the issue `.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "")` !!

Comment: For loading credentials in node.js app: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

Comment: Yes!  The .replace() bit was the magic I needed! Thanks from the future to the past.  jb

Answer (score 25):

Here's the code from one article I came across, posting below:

```
const imageUpload = async (base64) => {

  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  const { ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_REGION, S3_BUCKET } = process.env;

  AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));
  AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretAccessKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region: AWS_REGION });

  const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  const base64Data = new Buffer.from(base64.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');

  const type = base64.split(';')[0].split('/')[1];

  const userId = 1;

  const params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: `${userId}.${type}`, // type is not required
    Body: base64Data,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentEncoding: 'base64', // required
    ContentType: `image/${type}` // required. Notice the back ticks
  }

  let location = '';
  let key = '';
  try {
    const { Location, Key } = await s3.upload(params).promise();
    location = Location;
    key = Key;
  } catch (error) {
  }

  console.log(location, key);

  return location;

}

module.exports = imageUpload;
```

Read more: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

Credits: https://medium.com/@mayneweb/upload-a-base64-image-data-from-nodejs-to-aws-s3-bucket-6c1bd945420f

Comment: "new" keyword should not come before Buffer.from

Answer (score 19):

ok, this one is the answer [how to save canvas data to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867534/how-to-save-canvas-data-to-file/5971674#5971674)

basically it loos like this in my code

```
buf = new Buffer(data.dataurl.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')


req = knoxClient.put('/images/'+filename, {
             'Content-Length': buf.length,
             'Content-Type':'image/png'
  })

req.on('response', (res) ->
  if res.statusCode is 200
      console.log('saved to %s', req.url)
      socket.emit('upload success', imgurl: req.url)
  else
      console.log('error %d', req.statusCode)
  )

req.end(buf)
```

Comment: Buffer object will throw an error "Buffer not define" can you give me solution for that.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. you got any solution or not

Comment: @NaveenG  This is a node example, maybe you are using plain JS?

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer works great but if someone needs to accept any file instead of just images this regexp works great:

`/^data:.+;base64,/`

Answer (score -1):

For laravel developers this should work

The `$uploadFile` is the base64 encoded string you want to upload to S3 server. While the `$fileName` should contain the file extension e.g: `filename.png`. make sure this correspond to `data:image/{filetype}` of the base64 encode.

```php
/* upload the file  */
$path = Storage::putFileAs($uploadfolder, $uploadFile, $fileName, "s3");
```

make sure to set your .env file property before calling this method