# how to upload base64 data as image to s3 using node js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, base64

I am sending base64data of canvas to node.js script. I need the base64data to be stored as an image to the s3bucket. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for. [uploading-base64-encoded-image-to-s3][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511321/uploading-base64-encoded-image-to-amazon-s3-via-node-js

Answer (score 0):

1. Store your Data URI in a variable.
2. Create function which decodes your data URI(64 bit encoded string) to string(Here I have created dataURItoBlob() function) and after decoding return the string.
3. Pass that string to in body of S3 upload function.

   ```
    var myDataUri = "data:image/jpg;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYW..."

    var myFile=dataURItoBlob(myDataUri);

    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        var array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
         array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
      }
     return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
        type: 'image/jpg'
    });
    }
    if (myFile)) {
      results.innerHTML = '';
      var params = {
        Key: fileName+'.jpg',
        ContentType: 'image/jpg',
        Body: myFile
      };

    bucket.upload(params, function(err, data) {
         results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.: ' + file;
       });
     } else {
    results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
   }
   ```

Comment: @lusha li, check for new blob check link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

Answer (score -5):

you can send base64 data with AWS putObject method as follows

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./s3_config.json');
var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'myBucket'} } );

var imageBase64Data='Your base64 code '

s3Bucket.putObject(imageBase64Data, function(err, data){
  if (err) { 
    console.log(err);
    console.log('Error uploading data: ', data); 
  } else {
    console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
  }
});
```