# jspdf - pdf uploaded directly to s3 with png, png is corrupt

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, jspdf

I am using the jspdf library along with Angular 5 to generate a PDF on the client side. I am adding a png image to the pdf.

I have generated my .png file using dataurl.net. When I add it to the pdf and use `doc.save()`, it downloads locally and it looks great and works perfectly. However, I am trying to upload it directly to s3, using `doc.output()` instead, and when it gets there it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHP6B.jpg

My code to PUT in to s3 looks like this:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
this.http.put(url, file, {headers})
```

with `file = doc.output()`

Anyone have any ideas of what may cause this?

Comment: I've actually noticed that saving the result of doc.output() locally has the same problem, so I suspect it is a problem with the jspdf library or the way I I am calling doc.output(), and nothing to do with angular/s3 or the upload process

Comment: looks like there is some difference in the character encoding or something of the stream data, you can see the diff here: https://quickdiff.net/?unique_id=9084579D-3251-D1F4-F253-FF170459FA69

Comment: jsfiddle with the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/96qcc4bd/

Comment: Seems like the data is same, but since it has binary stream in between. Converting it to string creates a problem here. Your best bet is to use the base64 data here and then send it to [aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511321/uploading-base64-encoded-image-to-amazon-s3-via-node-js)

Comment: I've tried sending the base64 version as well, but amazon doesn't seem to do anything on their end with that so it stays base64 encoded and results in 'corrupt pdf file'

Comment: How did you send the base64 data? Can you open the file in text and decode the base64 and see if there are no issues?

Comment: I am `PUT`ting it as outlined in the original question, have tried passing it different ways either as the raw data or the b64 encoded data. It has the same problem when I b64 decode the data, as you mentioned I do think that is a problem with converting it to a string

Comment: I meant to ask did you use `doc.output('datauristring')`? The cut the initial string to get the actual base64 data

Comment: yea I've tried that as well, as well as using it in combination with `new Buffer()`, `.toString('ascii')`, `.toString('binary')`, etc. none of which are working :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to pass the ArrayBuffer to s3 to get it to work.

So the only code change was using `doc.output('arraybuffer')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ArrayBuffer to s3 to get it to work.

Only need to change doc.output('arraybuffer')

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue when I tried to pass an ArrayBuffer to s3. Instead I was able to convert the jspdf ArrayBuffer to a Buffer and send that as content to s3 like so:

```js
const arrayBuffer = doc.output('arraybuffer');
doc.close();

// convert to Buffer
const pdfBuffer = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
```