# AWS S3 Image Upload Error: Unsupported Body Payload Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try to upload a local image to an s3 bucket and keep getting
`Error: Unsupported body payload object`

The image can be `jpg`, `jpeg`, or `png`. I've read that images can only be uploaded to s3 as `base64` so I read the file as a base64 string using `readAsDataURL`, and then create a Buffer with it.

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(file)
const base64str = reader.result.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
const fileContent = Buffer.from(base64str,'base64')
```

The above code is executed on the react frontend where `fileContent` is set to a variable through a hook, and that variable gets PUT-ed to my server with

```
static uploadImage = (id, fileContent) => {
  return axios.put(ROOT_URL + "/images/" + id, fileContent);
}
```

Then its uploaded with

```
await s3.upload({
  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
  Key: KEY,
  Body: fileContent,
  ContentType: TYPE,
}).promise();
```

I have tried many different solutions I've found on this website, and still receive the error. Not sure what I am missing.

EDIT: Here is one of the threads that I found helpful, but did not fix the error.
[Uploading base64 encoded Image to Amazon S3 via Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511321/uploading-base64-encoded-image-to-amazon-s3-via-node-js?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you read that images must be base64, but you can simply read the file content with something like `fs` and upload it to S3 as it is.

```js
// Read content from the file
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

// Setting up S3 upload parameters
const params = {
  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
  Key: 'cat.jpg', // File name you want to save as in S3
  Body: fileContent
};

// Uploading files to the bucket
await s3.upload(params).promise();
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I read the file in react on the front end so I cannot use `fs`

Comment: @Spartan26783 your question says that the file is put on the server via a PUT request, and then on S3. I assumed that happens after is already on the server.

Comment: "The above code is executed on the react frontend where `fileContent` is set to a variable through a hook, and that variable gets PUT-ed to my server"

So I am setting the file to a variable using react hook, and then using a put request to send that to the server.

Comment: Any updates? I've attempted some more solutions now. Any idea why AWS may not be accepting base64 strings? Also still looking for an `fs` workaround, the only that I can think of is `FileReader`