# How to upload canvas data uri to amazon s3 server

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, hapi.js

Right now, I've passed the canvas data URI string

> (data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAADwCAYAAABxLb1rAAAgAElEQVR.....
>   )

to my hapi (NodeJS) server.

My question is:

What are my next steps to "stream"/upload this data to Amazon S3 and create an actual image there?

Comment: So the real question is, how do you upload from nodejs to amazon S3.

Comment: You need to create a stream from this base64 image and upload the stream to S3

Comment: If when you search SO already you find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511321/uploading-base64-encoded-image-to-amazon-s3-via-node-js?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867534/how-to-save-canvas-data-to-file/5971674#5971674 ?  Let me guess you did not even search.

Answer (score 1):

before send object to s3 you must transform base64 to buffer and after send, for example:

```
var buf = new Buffer(b64string, 'base64');
s3.putObject({/*some  params*/, Body: buf}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

After this you send data to s3 and you will can open image without decode.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Store your Data URI in a vaiable.
2. Create function which decodes your data URI(64 bit encoded string) to string(Here I have created **dataURItoBlob()** function) and after decoding return the string
3. Pass that string to in **body** of **S3 upload function**

   ```
   var myDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYW..."

   var myFile=dataURItoBlob(myDataUri);

   function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
      console.log('1: ',dataURI);
      var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
      var array = [];
      console.log('2: ',binary.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
         array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
      }
     return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
     type: 'application/pdf'
     });
   }

    if (myFile)) {
      results.innerHTML = '';
      var params = {
        Key: new Date().getTime() + '.pdf',
        ContentType: 'application/pdf',
        Body: myFile
      };

     bucket.upload(params, function(err, data) {
       results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.: ' + file;
     });
    } else {
    results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
   }
   ```