# How to post WebRTC captured photo to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, post

I'm following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) example to let the user take a photo and send it to Node server. I tried to print the data on client side and it gives a long text. The picture is printed out in an `img` tag. I tried to use ajax to send that data to the server and parse it into a picture then save it but it doesn't work. The `req.body` is still empty. Can anyone explain how can I get information in that `img` tag and post it to the server and if it comes to the server, how does it look like and how to save the picture to a directory in the project? Thanks.

**Client-side data**

[image]

**HTML tag**

```
<div class="output">
    <img id="photo" name="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box.">
</div>
```

**front end js**

```
function takepicture() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (width && height) {
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        photo.setAttribute('src', data);
        alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/" ,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (dataR) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
            }
        });
    } else {
        clearphoto();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867534/how-to-save-canvas-data-to-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

First I have to pass the canvas URL to a hidden field and after that submit the field. When the server receives the string, I can use `base64-img` to parse the string back to image and save the image.